# HTML How to prompt a Message Box when the User clicks a sentence

Tags: javascript, html

I have the simple text: "What is this?" on a HTML page.

Without making it a button, is there a way to simply prompt a message box when the user clicks the text?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is using Javascript:

```
<a href="#" onClick="alert('Hello World!');">What is this</a>
```

(The `#` will make the page jump to the top after the click, but [there are ways to prevent it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493175/how-can-i-create-an-empty-html-anchor-so-the-page-doesnt-jump-up-when-i-click), and some will [discourage its usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0). The JavaScript can be put on the `href` as well, but [it's not considered good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick).)

But it doesn't necessarily *need* to be a `<a>` anchor, it can be any HTML element:

```
<span onClick="alert('Hello World!');">What is this</span>
```

If it is not a `<a>`, `<button>` or any other element where it is usual to indicate user interaction, you need to stilize it or otherwise indicate it is clickable somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You can add click handler to any element, not only a button.

```
<span onclick="showMsg()">What is this?</span>
```

Answer (score -3):

This is a good JavaScript way of doing it:

```
`<script language=JavaScript>
 <a href = "#" onMouseOver=" alert("THIS IS SPARTA!!");"> What is this? </a>"
 </script>`
```

Make sure to put this within the body of the html.

Comment: HTML 3.2, a link to the top of the page, and intrinsic event attributes. Everything about this is obsolete. It's also wrong since the question is asking about *clicking* and this uses onmouseover.