# why is "href" attribute needed in "a" tag in FB share code

Tags: html, css

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Apologies if this is a beginner question. But why is "href" there? What purpose does it serve? I am not getting its purpose.

I am assuming "onclick" a new window will be opened which has all the information in it about the link to be shared and the FB target destination.

Then why is "href" there????

Comment: Gives it the link "feel", pointer finger and all. This is bad practice, it should be using a styled span.

Comment: `href="#` is bad practise, but a styled span is *worse* practise as it can't be navigated to without a pointing device (so it really hurts, for example, screen reader users). It should have a real URL to be visited if the JavaScript fails for any reason.

Comment: Hmm...so @Quentin -- Would you just use an actual `a` with a failsafe `href`?

Comment: @tymeJV — Yes, that is what the last sentence of my comment says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML anchors (`<a>` tags) define clickable links, but only if the `href` attribute is present. (It is possible to not have the `href` element, but either a `name` or `id` instead; in this case it is not a clickable link, but rather a *destination* for a link). [See the HTML specification for more detail](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html).

The `#` element on a `href` attribute indicates a predefined anchor, for instance, `http://domain.com/page#section`. In this case, when the link is clicked the browser will open the page at `http://domain.com/page`, and in its HTML the browser expects a section called `#section`, defined by a `<a name="section">` on its code. Upon finding this section, the browser will position the screen at this position.

**When the section isn't specified, just the `#` is provided, it means *it's a link pointing to the local page* (or more specifically, the top of it)**. If the page isn't at the top, it jumps to the top. If it is at the top, nothing happens.

You can test it by creatin an HTML file with a `<a href="#">text</a>` link, it will be clickable, but there will be no effect (the only effect is, if it isn't at the top, it will jump to the top).

The `return false;` at the end of the JavaScript code [is there to prevent the "jump to the top"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493175/how-can-i-create-an-empty-html-anchor-so-the-page-doesnt-jump-up-when-i-click), if you remove it, the browser will position its view at the top of the page upon clicking.

Some will argue that `href` should always point to actual links and using `#` placeholders is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

It specifies where the URL goes to. In this case it's set to # meaning it won't open up a URL but instead will do nothing. It's telling the 'a tag' that this function will DO something.

See it as a default measure.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Tags `<a>` are not considered as *clickable links* if they does not contains a *href*.